# add_edge causing "no function to call error"

Tags: c++, boost, graph, edges

I'm getting a "no function to call" on my add_edge function. Boost is definitely included correctly, so I don't think that's the issue. Here is the function it's called in:

```
void initializeGraph(Graph &g,
                  Graph::vertex_descriptor &start,
                 Graph::vertex_descriptor &end, ifstream &fin)
// Initialize g using data from fin.  Set start and end equal
// to the start and end nodes.
{
edgeProperties e;

int n, i, j;
int startId, endId;
fin >> n;
fin >> startId >> endId;
Graph::vertex_descriptor v;

// Add nodes.
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    v = add_vertex(g);
    if (i == startId)
        start = v;
    if (i == endId)
        end = v;
}

while (fin.peek() != '.')
{
    fin >> i >> j >> e.weight;
    add_edge(i,j,e,g);
}
}
```

And here is how I called the function:

```
Graph g;
Graph::vertex_descriptor start, end, curr;
initializeGraph(g, start, end, infile);
```

Any ideas on why this is happening would be great because I'm really lost!

Comment: @ConfusedByCode it refers to the boost library defined function "add_vertex"

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @ConfusedByCode Yep, all the other boost functions I am using work just fine, so that's why I'm so confused

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: @ConfusedByCode "no matching function for call to 'add_edge' "

Comment: "No matching function call" means the function cannot be called with the arguments you supplied

Comment: @ConfusedByCode https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/MutablePropertyGraph.html

Answer (score 0):

You fail to deliver a self-contained example. Piecing together the bare minimum from the things I see, there is no problem:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4728839bcc46d4a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <fstream>

struct edgeProperties {
    double weight;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS,boost::directedS, boost::no_property, edgeProperties>;

void initializeGraph(Graph &g, Graph::vertex_descriptor &start, Graph::vertex_descriptor &end, std::ifstream &fin)
// Initialize g using data from fin.  Set start and end equal to the start and end nodes.
{
    edgeProperties e;

    int n, i, j;
    int startId, endId;
    fin >> n;
    fin >> startId >> endId;
    Graph::vertex_descriptor v;

    // Add nodes.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        v = add_vertex(g);
        if (i == startId)
            start = v;
        if (i == endId)
            end = v;
    }

    while (fin.peek() != '.' && fin >> i >> j >> e.weight) {
        add_edge(i, j, e, g);
    }
}

#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("input.txt");
    Graph g;
    Graph::vertex_descriptor start, end/*, curr*/;
    initializeGraph(g, start, end, infile);

    print_graph(g);
}
```

For input.txt:

```
5
0 4
2 3 1
1 2 1
3 4 1
0 2 1
.
```

Prints:

```
0 --> 2 
1 --> 2 
2 --> 3 
3 --> 4 
4 -->
```